# Is Optional<List> bad practice?

Tags: java

I keep seeing some users saying that using a collection with an optional is not recommended / is bad practice. I couldn't find much information on why it would be bad practice, so here I am.

In case it matters, in my particular case I have a JpaRepository with 2 methods. One `Optional<List> getValues()` and a second `List getDefaultValues()`, as such:

```
public interface someRepository extends JpaRepository<x, y> {

    Optional<List> getValues();

    List getDefaultValues();
}
```

The idea is that the values might not be present so I want to force the method caller to do `.orElse(getDefaultValues())` so there is no chance getting returned an empty List. I also figured it would be tidier than just doing something like this:

```
List list = getValues();

if (list.isEmpty()) {
   list = getDefaultValues();
}
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Edit: I realise my example is not the most well suited to the question, as pointed out in the answers below. However, I would still like to understand why `Optional<List>` is considered bad practice by some.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102481/java-optionalt-questions-am-i-doing-this-right) does not really answer my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Optional<T> questions, am I doing this right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102481/java-optionalt-questions-am-i-doing-this-right)

Comment: Why don't you return the default values if the list is empty or null?

Comment: _If_ you're going to use `Optional`, you'll want to use `.orElseGet()` instead of `orElse()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33170109/difference-between-optional-orelse-and-optional-orelseget

Comment: some reading:
https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/12-recipes-for-using-the-optional-class-as-its-meant-to-be-used
https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/the-java-optional-class-11-more-recipes-for-preventing-null-pointer-exceptions

Comment: Why not just have a single `List getValues()` method and hide the implementation details behind that? Or does the caller need to be aware that default values have been returned?

Comment: I wish you say some reasons of those who don't support Optional. I'm on your side.

Comment: AFAIK `isPresent` only checks for `null`, with that said, it would always return true. [here](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Optional.java#L158-L160)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the point is moot. There are two possible cases:

**1. The caller needs to be aware that default values have been returned**
In this case, the caller will not be able to use the `orElse()`/`orElseGet()` construct, and will have to check with `isPresent()`. This is no better than checking whether the list is empty.

**2. The caller does not need to be aware that default values have been returned**
In which case you might as well hide the implementation details behind a single `List getValues()` method that returns the default values in case no values were found.

---

As to the general applicability of using `Optional<List>`, I think the Brian Goetz quote from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/3558960) says it best:

> Our intention was to provide a limited mechanism for library method
> return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no
> result", and using null for such was overwhelmingly likely to cause
> errors.

When it comes to lists (and collections in general), there is already a clear way to represent "no result", and that is an empty collection.

Comment: Those are good points. I might have just opted for Optional purely because it was the "cheaper" solution in the moment, though I realise your case 2 is probably the best approach.

Comment: I'd still like some thoughts on the overarching question though. I can't quite wrap my head around the bad practice argument.

Comment: @valegians My assumption would be that is inherited from the bad practice of returning `null` vs an empty collection. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970001). It's about C#, but the same applies to Java.) [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555) from Brian Goetz (one of Java's language architects) might also be relevant.

Comment: @Ivar RobbyCornelissen Thank you both for the input. It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Lets first consider this example:

```
public class <X> Example {

    public List<X> getValues() {
        if (...) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return /* a non-empty list */
        }
    }

    public List<X> getValuesAgain() {
        if (...) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        } else {
            return /* a non-empty list */
        }
    }
}
```

Which of those ways of returning no values is better?

I would argue that the better way is (nearly always) the way that `getValuesAgain` does it; i.e. by returning an empty list.  Consider the following.

With the first version, I need to test for a `null` before using the result:

```
  List<String> l = example.getValues();
  if (l != null) {
      for (s String: l) {
          /* do something */
      }
  }
```

With the second version, I can use the result directly:

```
  List<String> l = example.getValuesAgain();
  for (s String: l) {
      /* do something */
  }
```

In short, returning `null` makes life more complicated for the caller compared with returning an empty list.  In theory, you may have saved the creation of an empty list object ... except that the javadoc for `emptyList()` states that it doesn't need to return a *distinct* list object each time.  (And it typically won't!)

Now consider what `Optional<List<String>>` means: either a `List<String>` or no value.  But as we have already seen, returning an empty list is simpler for the caller that returning a `null`.  And the same logic applies here too.

So if `getValues` returns an `Optional<List<X>>`, we would need to use it like this:

```
  Optional<List<String>> l = example.getValues();
  if (l.isPresent()) {
      for (s String: l.get()) {
          /* do something */
      }
  }
```

Compare with the original `getValuesAgain`:

```
  List<String> l = example.getValuesAgain();
  for (s String: l) {
      /* do something */
  }
```

---

In short, using `Optional` to return a list or `null` is not an improvement.

The only scenario where I think you should contemplate using `Optional<List<?>>` as a return type is if the API **needs** to make a *semantic distinction* between an empty list versus no list.

The same applies for other collection types, and also for arrays, strings and other examples.

---

Another way of thinking about this is that the *designers' intention* for `Optional` is to provide a way to indicate there is "no result"; see Brian Goetz's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328555/139985).  But we don't need to indicate there is "no result" here since we can return an empty collection.